# Regex pattern + Apex

Tags: regex, salesforce, apex

I have OS Pattern: X.X.X.X-OptXXX

From the above patter I needed to get the parent OS version that is X.X.X.X alone from X.X.X.X-OptXXX.

I need to get the parent OS version and assign to the field via Apex Trigger.

Comment: `string.split("-")[0]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think we can actually do a bit better than `split`, which still uses a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34267303/2642059

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [`substringBefore`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substringBefore) command. Which will construct a `String` containing the characters preceding a specific character. [As mentioned by Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263758/regex-patter-apex#comment56268913_34263758) since you know that you want to break the input `String` at the `'-'` character, if your input was: `String OSPattern = 'X.X.X.X-OptXXX';` You can find the "parent OS version" `String` like this:

```
String parentOSVersion = OSPattern.substringBefore('-');
```